# linux print just Outgoing bandwidth

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

i want to get just the outgoing bandwidth example "343 MBit/s"

so i want a command to get  just this example:   "343 MBit/s"

so it can be

```
nload
```

or iftop  command

example:

```
 rates:    270Mb   244Mb   283Mb
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

```
iftop -t -s 1 -n -N 2>/dev/null | awk '/Total send rate:/ {print $6}'
```

this is command from which i get just example: 149Mb